# Vlook up from different sheet with VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to Vlookup from sheet1 column B, I have my reference values in sheet2 in column B. Below is my code. I'm trying to look up with the help of VBA but only first row is getting populated. Rest it is not getting populated. Can someone help me with this?

```
Sub vl()
    Set rngLast = Range("B1").Offset(Rows.Count - 1).End(xlUp)

    With Range("B2", rngLast)
        .Offset(0, 0).FormulaR1C1 = "=VLOOKUP(RC[-1],Sheet2!C[-1]:C,2,0)"
        .Value = .Offset(0, 0).Value
    End With

End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure you want to get the last row depending on *Column B*? Seems as if *Column A* contains the values which depends the last row. So try:

```
Sub vl()
    Set rngLast = Range("A1").Offset(Rows.Count - 1).End(xlUp).Offset(0, 1)

    With Range("B2", rngLast)
        .FormulaR1C1 = "=VLOOKUP(RC[-1],Sheet2!C[-1]:C,2,0)"
        .Value = .Value
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: up one for pointing out that the same column being populated with formula is the reference to the `rnglast` variable.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `A1 notation` but use `.Formula` property instead.
Might as well include the sheet object in your `With Clause` to make it explicit. Something like:

```
Dim rnglast As Range

With Sheets("Sheet1")
    Set rnglast = .Range("B" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp)
    With .Range("B2", rnglast)
        .Formula = "=VLOOKUP(A2,Sheet2!B:C,2,0)"
        .Value = .Value
    End With
End With
```

Also `Offset` is good but you don't need to use it if not necessary.

**Edit1:**

Axel also pointed out that you might be referencing the `rnglast` wrongly.
If you need to get the last cell with data in *Column A* then you should reference it to *A*.
 The approach would then be:

```
Dim rowlast As Long

With Sheets("Sheet1")
    rowlast = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    With .Range("B2:B" & rowlast)
        .Formula = "=VLOOKUP(A2,Sheet2!B:C,2,0)"
        .Value = .Value
    End With
End With
```

Comment: @Kiran Ah I've edited my post. That is pointed out by Axel in his post as well.

Comment: Thanks L42 and @Axel. I was wrongly referencing the rnglast wrongly. As suggested I have amended the code accordingly. Appreciate your help on it. Have a nice day ahead :)